# Rebuild array with standard keys

Tags: php, arrays

I made a script where basically I explode a string, for example:

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
```

And I make a condition where if it's true, I have to unset the first value of the array (with key 0)

```
if (condition) {
    unset($pieces[0]);
```

The problem is that when I unset the first value, it make the array start with key 1, and I need it to start with key 0 since I have to merge the values with a parallel array.

So, the question is: anyone know a function in order to rebuild array with standard keys (from 0 to n). Thanks.

Comment: use array_values($pieces)

Comment: from the doc: `array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (condition) {
    array_shift($pieces);
}

print_r($pieces);
```

Comment: array_shift — Shift an element off the beginning of array

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use array_values to reset all the keys.

```
if (condition) {
   unset($pieces[0]);
   $pieces = array_values($pieces);
}
```

If you remove item [5], it will make [6] -> [5]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP array_shift() function to remove the first element or value from an array. The array_shift() function also returns the removed value of array. However, if the array is empty (or the variable is not an array), the returned value will be NULL.

```
<?php
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);

// Deleting first array item
$removed = array_shift($pieces);
print_r($pieces);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($removed);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => piece2 [1] => piece3 [2] => piece4 [3] => piece5 [4] => piece6 ) 
// Removed
    string(6) "piece1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_values`

```
$pieces = array_values($pieces);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$arr = explode(" ", $pizza);
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if($v == 'piece3' || $v == 'piece5') {
        array_splice($arr, $k, 1);
    }
}
print_r($arr);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => piece1
//     [1] => piece2
//     [2] => piece4
//     [3] => piece5
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the array_filter function. It makes you able to use even more complex decisions.

```
$result = array_filter($pieces, function($index) {
    return $index > 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```